Building GuestAdditions failed on guest RHEL9 due to read-only member ‘vm_flags’
We have a system of:

VirtualBox hypervisor v7.0.18 running on Windows 10, with a
guest OS of RHEL9, and "uname -r" says its kernel release is "5.14.0-503.14.1.el9_5.x86_64".

After upgrading to the above kernel version by "dnf update", we are trying to rebuild the VirtualBox GuestAdditions and got the following error in the log file saying /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:1447:39: error: assignment of read-only member ‘vm_flags’.
More details of the interesting parts in the log file:
Building the main Guest Additions 7.0.18 module for kernel 5.14.0-503.14.1.el9_5.x86_64.
Error building the module.  Build output follows.
make V=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL= -C /lib/modules/5.14.0-503.14.1.el9_5.x86_64/build M=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j1 modules
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (                \
echo >&2;                                                       \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
echo >&2 ;                                                      \
/bin/false)

...

In file included from /tmp/vbox.0/combined-os-specific.c:43:
/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c: In function ‘rtR0MemObjNativeLockUser’:
/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:1447:39: error: assignment of read-only member ‘vm_flags’
 1447 |                 papVMAs[rc]->vm_flags |= VM_DONTCOPY | VM_LOCKED;
      |                                       ^~
/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c: In function ‘rtR0MemObjNativeMapUser’:
/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:1929:35: error: assignment of read-only member ‘vm_flags’
 1929 |                     vma->vm_flags |= VM_DONTEXPAND | VM_DONTDUMP;
      |                                   ^~
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:249: /tmp/vbox.0/combined-os-specific.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1944: /tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
make: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile-footer.gmk:133: vboxguest] Error 2
Could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System, skipping.
kernel modules and services were not reloaded


Searching for the error message error: assignment of read-only member ‘vm_flags’ found Bug#1038003: xtrx-dkms: module fails to build for Linux 6.3: error: assignment of read-only member 'vm_flags'. While that referenced bug is not on VirtualBox it does explain the reason for the error:

This bug is caused by kernel commit bc292ab00f6c
("mm: introduce vma->vm_flags wrapper functions").
So all the vma->vm_flags |= VM_XXXD needs to be modifed to vm_flags_set(vma,
VM_XXX).

[PATCH v4 2/7] mm: introduce vma->vm_flags wrapper functions is from the Linux Kernel mailing list which contains the Kernel change which:

Changed the vm_flags field to be read-only.
Added vm_flags_init, vm_flags_reset, vm_flags_set, vm_flags_clear and vm_flags_mod access functions.

Since the Linux Kernel API is not guaranteed to be stable between releases, "out of tree" Kernel modules such as the VirtualBox Guest Additions moudule may fail to compile after a Kernel update which changes the API.
The other answer says updating the VirtualBox version resolved the issue. Therefore, for this answer are providing some background information rather than investigating how the change the VirtualBox Guest Additions module source code to fix the compile error.

We resolved the issue by upgrading VirtualBox to, v7.1.4, the latest current version.
We did not get a chance to test the later patch versions of VirtualBox v7.0.x, although it would be best to verify as well.
